# How to schedule function calls with JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web application that scrapes data from a page on another domain. This data is updated at a specific time several times a week, lets say 2pm on a Wednesday and a Friday.

I have a JS function which scrapes specific data from this page and stores it in a database. How do I go about scheduling this function to be called at specific times?

Comment: Need more information.  Is your JS function running on NodeJS?  What is your server architecture, etc?

Comment: I've a feeling that you are scraping client site with some proxy to scrape cross domain. Can you give more info ?

Comment: This is a real question. Just wanted to do the same — call a function at 11:00AM. If someone can't understand the question, it doesn't mean it's 'unreal'.

Answer (score 9):

You use the `setTimeout()` function.  It takes two parameters, a function to call and a number of milliseconds from now.

```
setTimeout(myFunction, 10 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: Why the downvotes?  This is javascript.  As I understand the question, it's a question about scheduling a function call for the future in javascript and `setTimeout()` is how you do that.

Comment: +1, just to balance the -1's. I think, OP doesnt want this answer, but what he has described in his question, for that its a correct answer.

Comment: Missed calculating the difference between now and the scheduled time. +1 to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

I'd setup a cron job using `crontab -e` (on OSX):

```
* 14 * * 4,6 /usr/local/bin/node /path/to/script.js
```

This will run the script using `node` (wherever you happen to have it installed) every Wednesday and Friday at 2PM.

Comment: Cron really is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Nodejs has a module `node-cron` that uses `setTimeout` to schedule the next run of a job after completing the current.  You could look up the sourcecode of that and port it to your application.